# ASP.NET MVC6 scaffolding doesn't work in BETA 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using **ASP.NET Beta 8** trying to get scaffolding to work but it getting an issue with the **Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration**

My `project.json`

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration"
  },
```

Command :

```
dnx gen controller -Name ModelClassName--datacontext MyDbContext --model ModelClassName
```

Error:

```
dnx : Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration'. Available commands: web, ef, gen.
```

This package is on Nuget but it hasn't been updated for Beta 8.

Only version is Beta 5. [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration/)

When I install this Beta 5 package

> Install-Package Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration -Pre

and run the same scaffolding command I get the error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager'

This makes me think scaffolding doesn't work in Beta 8.

Comment: Make sure there wasn't any Breaking Change in namespaces between beta releases. This happens very often and is usually reported on Github. Take a look at [Announcements](http://github.com/aspnet/Announcements)

Comment: Could you please provide your dependencies in your project.json?

Answer (score 5):

for all using rc1-final just change the namespace in commands to

"gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration"

Answer (score 0):

Beta 5 packages should not be mixed with Beta 8.

This package seem to not have been updated which means that this code is technically dead and/or has been merged in another DNX project. I've seen `ILibraryManager` in the `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` namespace.

As said in my comment, you probably have a version mismatch. Ensure to use `1.0.0-beta8` package specifically (no `1.0.0-*`). I would do a `File > New Project` with the beta8 and check what the `gen` command is using in the new template.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015, you should add a package source that points to  aspnetmaster.

Go to Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources
Add a new package name it whatever you like ex. mygetv3 an set the source to
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json

Place it first in the list.

In project.json -> "dependencies" add "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta8"
and in "commands" add       "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration"

now you can use it as you did in beta5 ex.:

dnx gen controller -name NameController --dataContext DbContext --model ModelName  -l _Layout -f

Answer (score 0):

Working scaffolding wasn't included in BETA 8. It was fixed again in RC1

Answer (score 0):

In rc-update1, the namespaces have changed:

**FROM:** Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration

**TO:** Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration

So instead of installing `Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration`, just add `Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc` to your project.json

**project.json**

```
"dependencies": {
...
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
}

"commands": {
...
"gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration"
}
```

**Customizing the MVC6 scaffolding templates**

To customize the MVC6 scaffolding templates, you will find them in the folder: C:\Users\ `{user}` .dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc\ `1.0.0-rc1-final` \Templates

To create a project specific set of templates, just copy the Templates folder into the root folder of your project (i.e. same folder as project.json) and when you use `dnx gen scaffolding` it will use these locally customised templates